# key already added for dictionary - thread problem?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, thread-safety

I need some help getting my head around thread safety and dictionaries. When adding to a dictionary I get an error saying "An item with the same key has already been added" (when I say I get it, I haven't actually been able to replicate this but have seen it in the error logs).

From what I can see when reading similar questions it's likely to have something to do with thread safety, but I'm still not clear on what's happening. And as it's hard to test, especially when I can't replicate it, I'm hoping that someone might be able to explain or point me in the right direction. It's an asp.net web application (C#), and the error is happening when getting a quiz tailored for the specific user. I'm also getting errors trying to accessing keys that doesn't exist, but one thing at a time!

I've made a mini example where I've stripped out everything I didn't think was necessary to show the problem. If I've stripped out too much let me know.

```
public class QuizDataAdapterFactory
{
    private static IQuizDataAdapter q_adapter = new MyQuizDataAdapter();

    public static IQuizDataAdapter Create()
    {
        return q_adapter;
    }
}

IQuizDataAdapter dataAdapter = QuizDataAdapterFactory.Create();

public class MyQuizDataAdapter : IQuizDataAdapter
{
    private Quiz quiz;

    public Quiz GetQuiz()
    {
        quiz = new Quiz();
        quiz.QuestionIndex = new Dictionary<Guid, QuestionBase>();

        GetQuestions();

        return quiz;
    }

    private void GetQuestions()
    {
        Item[] items;

        foreach (Item questionItem in items)
        {
            Question newQuestion = new Question();
            PopulateQuestionFromItem(newQuestion, questionItem);
            questions.Add(newQuestion);

            // this is where it fails
            quiz.QuestionIndex.Add(questionItem.ID.ToGuid(), newQuestion);
        }
    }
}
```

Would adding `[ThreadStatic]` for the IQuizDataAdapter do the trick?

Thanks,

Annelie

Comment: Is this code accessed by multiple threads?

Comment: @Tony - Nope, just a regular page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only ever creating *one* instance of `MyQuizDataAdapter` due to your `Create` method being completely inappropriately named - it doesn't "create" an adapter, it returns the same one every time!

Create a different one each time instead, and you'll at least be in a better position... admittedly I don't much like the way that every time you call `GetQuiz` it repopulates the quiz in `MyQuizDataAdapter` too, but that's another step...

Comment: Wow, I'm honoured by getting an answer from the mighty Skeet! :) I'm changing it to create a different one, and I've also just had a chat with the developer who wrote the code and he said I might as well get rid of the factory too as it's not doing anything now. Thanks!

Comment: As for the GetQuiz, maybe I've stripped out too much code to make sense of that (if not any refactoring suggestions are most welcome!). GetQuiz takes a quizID as a parameter then goes to Sitecore and gets the correct quiz item before building the quiz.

Comment: @annelie: In that case, I wonder whether the problem is really that you're "storing" the Quiz that you're creating. Why is GetQuestions in MyQuizDataAdapter rather than in Quiz? If it should really be in MyQuizDataAdapter, it should return just the questions, rather than adding them to the Quiz. Basically the information is being stored too widely as far as I can see.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I think GetQuestions does belong in MyQuizDataAdapter, but perhaps the question index isn't such a good idea? The dictionary is created, according to his comment in Quiz.cs, to "Hold an index of all questions so you don't need to traverse the tree each time". Maybe I should move that?

Comment: @annelie: It sounds reasonable for that to be in Quiz - but the data adapter should *just* return the questions, and let the Quiz add the questions to itself, IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I've viewed the logs and the error hasn't happened again, so this seems to have solved it. I'll look into doing some refactoring as well. Thanks for all the help!